# How to cast (long to wide) dataframe based on some conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, casting

How can I convert this:

```
patient_id test    test_value      date_taken
11964    HBA1C         8.60        2017-06-14
11964    Glucose     231.00        2017-05-01
11964    Glucose     202.00        2017-07-01
11964    Glucose     194.00        2017-09-02
11964    Creatinine    1.10        2017-05-01
11964    Creatinine    1.28        2017-08-14
```

to this?

```
patient_id  hba1c_earliest hba1c_latest hba1c_change glucose_earliest glucose_latest/
    11964      8.60           8.60          0.0000        231.0           194.0   
glucose_change creatinine_earliest creatinine_latest creatinine_change
     -0.1602         1.10               1.28             0.1636
```

For the extended dataframe:

> `.*_earliest columns should include that lab result with the earliest date.
>   .*_latest columns should include that lab result with the latest date.
>   .*_change columns should hold the relative change (variation), (Latest - Earliest) / Earliest.`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
print (df.dtypes)
patient_id             int64 <- not necessary
test                  object <- not necessary
test_value           float64 <- necessary
date_taken    datetime64[ns] <- necessary
dtype: object

df = (df.sort_values(['patient_id','test','date_taken'])
       .groupby(['patient_id','test'])['test_value']
       .agg([('earliest','first'),('latest','last')])
       .assign(change = lambda x: (x['latest'] - x['earliest'])/ x['earliest'])
       .unstack()
       .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)
       .reindex(columns=df['test'].unique(), level=0)
       )
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   patient_id  HBA1C_earliest  HBA1C_latest  HBA1C_change  Glucose_earliest  \
0       11964             8.6           8.6           0.0             231.0   

   Glucose_latest  Glucose_change  Creatinine_earliest  Creatinine_latest  \
0           194.0       -0.160173                  1.1               1.28   

   Creatinine_change  
0           0.163636
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by multiple columns
2. Aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) for `earliest` and `latest` columns.
3. Create new column by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)
4. Rehape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)
5. Swap levels in MulriIndex in columns by [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html)
6. Then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same order like in original column
7. Flatten MultiIndex by `map` with `join` in columns
8. Last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from `index`.

Comment: gives me a bunch of errors like this `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in <lambda>(x)
   1035             if is_object_dtype(lvalues):
   1036                 return libalgos.arrmap_object(lvalues,
-> 1037                                               lambda x: op(x, rvalues))
   1038             raise
   1039 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: @Sang - I think is convert column to datetimes? `df['date_taken'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_taken'])` before my solution.

Comment: @Sang - And also try `df['test_value'] = df['test_value'].astype(float)`, if not working  `df['test_value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['test_value'], errors='coerce')` for convert column to numeric

Comment: How would you lowercase the `test` values during the transformation? I've tried adding `.apply(lambda x : x.lower())` in-between `.reindex(columns=df['test']` and `.unique(), level=0)` but that didn't work.

Comment: Also, is it possible to replace missing values with 0 as you go instead of additional line `df = df.fillna(0)`?

Comment: I tried the following and that didn't work either: `.reindex(columns=np.array([s.lower() for s in df['test'].unique()], dtype = 'object'), level=0)`

Comment: @RaminMelikov - I think simpliest is `df = df.reset_index().rename(columns=str.lower)`, your solution not working because original values are not lowercase

Comment: Figured it out: `df.columns = ['_'.join(t).lower() for t in df.columns]`. Also, there is no need for this line: `.reindex(columns=df['test'].unique(), level=0)`